# use .on with .one jquery? is it possible?

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
$(".show").one("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
    });
});
```

My problem is that I need to use `on()` and this `one()` together. How can I use `on()` and `one()` in the same expression?

```
$(document).on("click", ".show", function() { // how to use one?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`one()` has a delegated selector too:

```
$(document).one("click", ".show", function() {
    // this code block will only execute once...
});
```

Note that for best performance you should select the nearest parent element to `.show` which is in the DOM when the page loads, instead of using the `document`.

More info in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.